# SQL datatype to store 01 and 10

Tags: mysql, database, types

I have a select element, which has some values from 0 to 12,
 the code for select element,

```
           <select name="months">
                <option>--Month--</option>
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1" >1</option>
                <option value="2" >2</option>
                <option value="3" >3</option>
                <option value="4" >4</option>
                <option value="5" >5</option>
                <option value="6" >6</option>
                <option value="7" >7</option>
                <option value="8" >8</option>
                <option value="9" >9</option>
                <option value="10" >10</option>
                <option value="11" >11</option>
                <option value="12" >12</option>
            </select>
```

I am using MySQL as Database and PHP for Backend Scripting, i have set datatype as float(in Database) to store these value, as there in year value to be appended with this data, as 1.10.
the problem is when i select 2 as year and 1 as month, it updates as 2.10 
and if i select 2 as year and 10 as month, it updates the same as above, 2.10.
how can i solve this problem?? 
NOTE: by using varchar it is possible.

Comment: What database are you using? Many SQL databases have date data types for storing dates.

Answer (score 3):

Don't reinvent date encoding in the database.  You should store it as a bona-fide date in the database.  The implementation varies depending on which database you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you use DateTime to store it, and then retrieve the individual components as needed?

I had the same problem, and believe me, using the right datatype is the better way.
You create an new DateTime object, and then alter the month and day as needed, save in database, and then when necessary retrieve that information, and use the DateTime.Month and such.

Comment: i think i can use Varchar instead of DateTime

Comment: Don't ever use Varchar instead of DateTime. It will come back to kick your rear end as soon as you'll try to select a range of dates.

Comment: sorry u didnt get the problem, actually i want to store the data as 2.10 years in data feild, and dont want any data or time, the problem was with 1 and 10, i want in case of 1 it should be 2.01 and in case of 10, it should be 2.10...

Answer (score 0):

You should be using one of the [`DateTime`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html) data types of MySql - using anything else means that computing and querying dates will be more difficult than it should be and will have more processing overhead.

Use the right datatype for the task.

Comment: actually i want to store data as 2.10 or 2.01 and not it date or time

Comment: @Harish - if you store it as a date, you can always display it in whatever manner you want.

Answer (score 0):

Is there some type of business rule that says you have to store it in a non DateTime format?

That's the only reason I can think of to not be using DateTime, and that information will give better parameters to answer the original question.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd even do it if there were a business rule. For a business rule, I'd store it in a sane way, and build a view that formatted the sane value in whatever way the business wanted. Now, if it were a statutory rule (a law) I'd do it, but even Congress isn't dumb enough to do that.